# How to return result of the url action

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sorry but I dont know how to clearly ask about this.

```
$user = User::find(session('user_id'));
    $api_user = 'USERAPI';
    $api_password = 'USERPASSWORD';
    $sms_from = 'KOLOS';
    $sms_to = $user->phone;
    $sms_msg = 'Your verification code is '. $user->phone_validation.'.';
    //$this->sendCode($api_user,$api_password,$sms_from,$sms_to,$sms_msg); // callback

    //$user = User::find(session('user_id'));
    $query_string = "api.aspx?apiusername=".$api_user."&apipassword=".$api_password;
    $query_string .= "&senderid=".rawurlencode($sms_from)."&mobileno=".rawurlencode($sms_to);
    $query_string .= "&message=".rawurlencode(stripslashes($sms_msg)) . "&languagetype=1";        
    $url = "http://gateway.onewaysms.co.id:10002/".$query_string;
    $arr = array($url);
    $fd = implode(',', $arr); 

    if ($fd) {                       
        if ($fd >= 0) {
            Print("MT ID : " . $fd);
            $ok = "success";
        } else {
            print("Please refer to API on Error : " . $fd);
            $ok = "fail";
        }
    } else {                       
        // no contact with gateway                      
        $ok = "fail. No contact";       
    }
```

This code snippet is working fine on my localhost, but not working on my godaddy hosting. Also if I go to the url directly, its sending the sms fine. Please someone tell me whats wrong with my code here.

From my title I have an idea, but don't know how to go to the url and then back to my app with the result.

Thank you so much.

Comment: use CURL. Read about it.

Comment: Use GuzzleHttp: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

This code is fine. There is no handshake between the two server. 
 please check the curl_connection on your godaddy server.